# Two formatting strings in one with only one value

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I want to have a string where I can format it with an integer so that it:

1. Adds a sign in front of the integer (+ for positive ints, - for negative ints)
2. Surround the signed int with parentheses (i.e. with ())
3. Left align the int with parentheses on the left, adding if necessary spaces to the end.

I know how to do these steps separately, but I haven't been able to combine them into a single string.
1 and 2 would be accomplished with for example `'({:+d})'.format(3)`, this would result in `(+3)`.
3 is done for an arbitrary string with `'{:<5}'.format(3)`, this would result in `3`     (4 trailing spaces).

My goal is to have a single string where I can call `.format` on only once, so
`format_string.format(3)`
would result in
`(+3)` 
with one trailing space to make the string length 5.

Is this possible?

I've tried `({{:+d}:<5})` but this doesn't work as it thinks `{:+d}` is the field name to format with `<5`, which is obviously not the case.
I've also looked into f-strings, but these are not suitable for my use case as I call `.format` on the format string later than when it's created.

Any help would be most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Solution with one call for `format`:

```
def special_format_int(n, SPACES=5):
    return '({:+d})'.format(n).ljust(SPACES)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd hoped for a way to only have to call format. Can you think of a way then?